# 04 pontiac grand am wont start

Tags: starting, pontiac, grand-am

Everything is working fine, but just getting a single click sound when trying to start, could be security system but don't think security light is on. Any solutions? Jump start didn't work either.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

If you are only getting a single click noise from the starter and a jump start doesn't make a difference, more than likely the solenoid on the start has gone bad or could be the brushes in the starter motor.

There is a thick copper washer at the back of the solenoid which allows power to be transferred from the positive cable of the battery directly to the starter. If this goes bad or gets to the point where it won't connect anymore, the starter will make behave like what you're talking.

Less likely, but still a concern, is if the brushes in the starter are worn out, they can no longer allow electricity to pass through and energize windings, which will also keep the starter motor from spinning.

Either way, I'd suggest your problem lies in the starter.

Comment: It was the stater, gave it a couple taps and it started right up, could it be that's it's going bad?

Comment: @user73107 - Absolutely.